# Data changes in vue script not reflected in browser output

Tags: vue.js

I have a few example vue js scripts so I thought I had understood the basics. But now things are not working which suggests I do not understand the basics. Can someone explain what is happening here.

```
<div id="breakingnews">
        <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" 
                id="purecss" v-on:submit.prevent="checkForm" 
                method="get">

              <fieldset>
                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label for="bnews">Breaking News</label>
                    <input id="bnews" type="text" v-model="bnews" placeholder="Headlines" required>
                </div>

                  <div class="pure-controls">
                      <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>

        </form>

        <h1>Breaking News</h1>  
        {{ display_bnews }}
        {{ message }}
    </div>
```

And the vue

```
let stompClient = null;

var vm = new Vue({
 el: ‘#breakingnews’,
 data: function () {
    return {
      bnews: ‘’,
      display_bnews: ‘’,
      message: ‘Hello Johnny’
    }
 },
 mounted: function () {
   let socket = new SockJS(’/gs-guide-websocket’);
   stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
   stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
   console.log('Connected: ’ + frame);

          stompClient.subscribe('/topic/bnews', function (val) {                    
            console.log("DEBUG: return val is " + val.body);                
            this.display_bnews = val.body;
            console.log("DEBUG: now display is " + this.display_bnews + " message is " + this.message);
            this.message = "Hello XXXXX";
            console.log("DEBUG: and now message is " + this.message);
          });
      });

 },
 methods:{
    checkForm: function (e) {
        console.log("DEBUG: checkForm " + this.bnews);
        stompClient.send("/app/bnews", {}, this.bnews);
    console.log("DEBUG: returned from stomp send");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
 }

})
```

So when I run, {{ message }} is displayed - “Hello Johnny”. I then send a headline which gives a console.log of:

```
DEBUG: checkForm Here is a Headline

SEND
destination:/app/bnews
content-length:18

Here is a Headline
DEBUG: returned from stomp send

<<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/bnews
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:j5s40qfk-9
content-length:18

Here is a Headline
DEBUG: return val is Here is a Headline
DEBUG: now display is Here is a Headline message is Hello XXXXX
DEBUG: and now message is Hello XXXXX
```

But display_bnews is not shown in the html and neither is message updated. So essentially, neither data variable is being updated in the html when it changes. But I thought that is what the {{ }} syntax did.

Where am I going wrong?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stomp calls are using `function` and as such you get a new `this`. You either save the vue's component `this` before the call, or use `fat arrow`.

Bellow an example using `fat arrow`:

```
stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
     console.log('Connected: ’ + frame);

     stompClient.subscribe('/topic/bnews', (val) => {                    
            console.log("DEBUG: return val is " + val.body);                
            this.display_bnews = val.body;
            console.log("DEBUG: now display is " + this.display_bnews + " message is " + this.message);
            this.message = "Hello XXXXX";
            console.log("DEBUG: and now message is " + this.message);
      });
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Does this mean that vue is using strict mode under the covers?